# SSIS Dynamic File Path

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dts

New to SSIS and trying to create a variable file path without a lot of joy, sure once I get it figured out once I will fine going forward, so any assistance would be great.

So I have a Variable `@[User::RvS_MonthVar]` which would be `202006`

So I am trying

```
"...\Reports\" + substring(@[User::RvS_MonthVar],1,4) + "\" + @[User::RvS_MonthVar] + "\" + "CN03.xls"
```

But I get an error

> The Token "\" is not recognised

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\` is an escape character in SSIS Expressions, you need to "double them up" when using them. For example:

```
"C:\\YourDirectory\\Reports" + @[User::Directory] + "\\" + @[User:FileName]
```

Comment: You're welcome, @GeoffCodd . If this helps, please do consider marking it as the solution, so that future readers know it was helpful. Thanks.